# function is not supported by the following of your targeted browsers

Tags: html, firefox

I have a problem ... I want to do some thing like upload file (picture) ... 
I do that code :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Upload Pic. !</title>

<style type="text/css">
div#mybutton {

  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;   

  width:  50px;
  height: 28px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: red;
}

div#mybutton:hover {
  background: green;
}

input#myfile {
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  font-size: 100px;
  z-index: 2;

  opacity: 0.0; 
  filter: alpha(opacity=0); 
  -ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=0)"; 
  -khtml-opacity: 0.0; 
  -moz-opacity: 0.0; 
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<form id="test_form" action="User_Finder.php">
 <div id="mybutton">
  <input type="file" id="myfile" name="upload"/>
 Click Me! 
</div>
</form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myfile').change(function(evt) {
        $('#test_form').submit();
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

but it does not work ....
I know why it doesnt work , you can see it by this picture :
http://im37.gulfup.com/u0SPB.png
...
I Looked long for solution of this problem in ggogle or here in stackoverflow but I did not find any answer...
Help me please ... thank you :)

Comment: Where are you including jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: Remove Internet Explorer 5.5 from your targets. (Nobody uses it anymore)

Go to Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > JavaScript

Comment: Thnk you @ohiresky ... it helped a lot :) ... but have you any idea about why the page it doesnot reloaded (not refreshed) when it submited ??

Comment: Are you including jQuery in your page?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the top of your page

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
<![endif]-->
```

It will suggest an upgrade path for all of your users that don't have a modern browser.